# Flutter dart dependency issue

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to have a webview inside my context body, but not to cover the entire screen space as I have to display a listview below it. 
I checked flutter_webview_plugin but it did not work

Getting the error :
That library is in a package that is not known. Maybe you forgot to mention it in your pubspec.yaml file?

```
  dependencies:
    flutter:
      sdk: flutter
    url_launcher: ^0.4.1
    async_loader: "^0.1.1"
    json_annotation: ^0.2.2
    flutter_webview_plugin: "^0.1.5"

    cupertino_icons: ^0.1.0
    #url_launcher: ^3.0.0

  dev_dependencies:
    flutter_test:
      sdk: flutter
    json_serializable: ^0.4.0`
```

I have written below line in my dart file

```
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';
```

Comment: Can you please update the `dependencies` in your question to exactly reflect the indentation as you have it in your file or check if it is exactly like I formatted it in your question. The way you copied it the formatting was totally broken which makes its content invalid.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a new package to your dependencies, then do a hot reload, you get the following misleading message:

```
Performing hot reload...
Your application could not be compiled, because its dependencies could not be 
established.
The following Dart file:
/usr/local/google/home/ianh/dev/release/startup_namer/lib/main.dart
...refers, in an import, to the following library:
package:package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart
That library is in a package that is not known. Maybe you forgot to mention it in 
your pubspec.yaml file?
Try again after fixing the above error(s).
```

Kill your application and start it again. This might solve your issue.

For more references please visit [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15879) git hub discussion

Answer (score 0):

Go to the build directory, which will be located at the top level of your app along with lib, ios, android, etc.

If a flutter_webview_plugin folder is not there, then you need to run `flutter pub get` to download the package.

If the folder is there, then it has already been downloaded. If that is the case and your IDE is still telling you that it does not recognize the package, then try restarting your IDE.